# Is the Paragon Gold Find bonus exempt from the cap?

Tags: diablo-iii

In patch 2.0.1, Paragon levels were completely reworked to grant bonus paragon points that you can invest in stats and perks to strengthen your character.  One of the options for [Utility points is increasing Gold Find](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/13020718/reaper-of-souls-first-look-paragon-20-2-21-2014), at a rate of 1% per point, up to a max of 50%.

However, Gold Find has a cap of 300%:

[image: Maximum Gold Find Tooltip]

I presume that the massive gold find bonus you get from higher difficulties is exempt from the 300% Gold Find cap, as it wouldn't make sense to offer rewards like 400% Gold Find if you couldn't use it all.  However, I'm less certain about the Paragon Gold Find bonus.

Is the 50% Gold Find you can gain from Paragon levels also exempt from this cap, or are those points wasted if you happen to have a lot of Gold Find on your gear?

Comment: Movespeed from Paragon points and movespeed from items have the same combined cap of 25%, so I would be surprised if it didn't work the same way for gold find.

Comment: So it's probably just a way to avoid "having" to have gold find/move speed on your items?

Comment: Yes I'd agree with that

Comment: I too agree with that assessment.

Comment: I agree with that as well.  @StrixVaria, go ahead and post that as an answer because I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#general). The hard cap for gold find was removed.

> The 300% Gold Find cap applied to items and Paragon Points has been
>   removed